# Can I grow pineapple plants from seed, rather than crowns?

Tags: containers, germination, seed-saving, optimal-conditions, bromeliads

The other day, as I was eating pineapple, I noticed that it was full of seeds (see pic below for what they look like). I have grown plants from the crowns on top of the fruit (even a couple patented ones that were mutated to prevent propagation - don't tell anyone :P), but I'm actually interested in starting *seeds*.

- What's the most efficient way to remove them from the fruits?
- Do they require special cleaning (I wonder because of the enzyme content of the fruit)
- How long do they store?
- Do they require treatment before sowing?
- What conditions do they require for good germination?

  - soil type
  - temperature
  - moisture
  - light
  - planting depth
- What kind of fertilizer is best, and when to start applying?
- How long until germination, and how long until fruiting-sized plants (under optimal conditions)?

Here's a picture of the seeds, for those who don't know how they look:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know the answer to all of your questions but I will try to answer what I can.

> What's the most efficient way to remove them from the fruits?

Cutting the pineapple into small chunks and extracting the seeds.

> Do they require special cleaning (I wonder because of the enzyme content of the fruit)?

Rinsing in water and drying on a towel.

> How long do they store?

Not sure about this one, but I would guess about a year.

> Do they require treatment before sowing?

A quick rinse in water.

> What conditions do they require for good germination?

A warm area without direct sunlight.

> - soil type
> - temperature

Warm

> - moisture

Moist after sprouting

> - light

Full sun

> - planting depth

Several centimeters deep.

> What kind of fertilizer is best, and when to start applying?

A 6-6-6 fertilizer after the seedlings have been transplanted to 1-3 gallon pots and they are 3in tall.

> How long until germination, and how long until fruiting-sized plants (under optimal conditions)?

- Germination can take a few weeks.
- From seed to a fruiting plant can take between 20 months and 3 years.

Source: Experience and http://www.ehow.com/how_7606004_grow-pineapples-seeds.html

Comment: For temperature, you said, 'warm'. That's ... really broad. I was looking for an actual ideal temperature range. Also, how deep is 'several centimeters'? idk, but it seems like you'd run into problem if planting more than 3 cm. deep.

Comment: Since pineapples are tropical, they would probably do well between 83F and 93F for sprouting. As for depth, I would go with 1-2cm deep. The article suggests sprouting in a glass jar but i've never tried that method.

Answer (score 3):

I put down twenty pineapple seeds picked out of fruit. Placed in seedling box with lid sprinkled soil over. Only one came up but its been 2 months n starting to look good

Comment: That's awesome!! If you could put more detail in, so that others can do the same thing, that'd be awesome too!